# Sceneform - How to add a Sphere Renderable?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I have a `ModelRenderable` (The main node) created and I'm trying to attach `Sphere Renderables` (Child nodes) using `LocalPosition` on the `Main node` to ensure that they maintain their position relative to the `Main node`.

The problem I'm coming across is that the `child nodes` are being placed in the wrong position (from what I'm expecting) when getting the `HitTestResult` from clicking on the back of the `Main node`.

Here is a gif demonstration:

[image]

Creating the Main Renderable:

```
private void createAndyRenderable(Node node) {
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this, Uri.parse(OBJ_NAME))
                .build()
                .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> {
                    node.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
                    node.setLocalPosition(NODE_STARTING_LOCAL_POSITION);
                })
                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load renderable" 
                            + throwable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                    return null;
                });
    }
```

Attaching an on Tap Handler:

```
private void addOnTapHandler() {
        mPersonNode.setOnTapListener((HitTestResult hitTestResult, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {

            Log.d(TAG, "addOnTapHandler: " + hitTestResult.getPoint());

            Color color = new Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#FF7390"));

            MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(this, color)
                    .thenAccept(material -> {
                        Renderable sphere = ShapeFactory.makeSphere(0.05f, Vector3.zero(), material);

                        Node node = new Node();
                        node.setParent(hitTestResult.getNode());
                        node.setLocalPosition(hitTestResult.getPoint());
                        node.setRenderable(sphere);

                    });
        });
    }
```

Using the code in OnCreate:

```
mScene = sceneView.getScene();
mPersonNode = new Node();
createAndyRenderable(mPersonNode);
mScene.addChild(mPersonNode);
addOnTapHandler();
```

**Edit: Code for rotate button**

```
@OnClick(R.id.rotate)
    public void rotate() {
        if (mCurrentNodeRotatedAngle == 180f) {
            Log.d(TAG, "rotate: Called 1 " + mCurrentNodeRotatedAngle);
            mCurrentNodeRotatedAngle = 0f;
            mPersonNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f), mCurrentNodeRotatedAngle));
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "rotate: Called 2 " + mCurrentNodeRotatedAngle);
            mCurrentNodeRotatedAngle = 180f;
            mPersonNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f), mCurrentNodeRotatedAngle));

        }

    }
```

```
mCurrentPosition = camera.getWorldPosition();
```

Comment: I'm not sure its clear what you mean by they are "placed in the wrong position (from what I'm expecting) " - if you could add some detail it might help get you some response?

Comment: What are you doing when for the "Rotate 180" button? It looks like the camera is still pointing at the "front" of the model and that is why the spheres are showing up on the front?

Comment: For the ```Rotate Button``` I'm doing just setting the Node's LocalRotation: ```mNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f), 180));``` I am not moving the camera position.

Comment: @Mick When I click on the back of the Andy obj I want it to place the spheres on the back of the model. But for some reason it's being placed on the front. It works with world position in my ```addOnTapHandler()```, but not with local position which is why I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Node HitTestResult  getPoint() is giving you World Coordinaets and I think you are using those directly as local coordinates? I think you probably need to experiment with mapping from the world coordinates to local coordinates to get the effect you want.